# Compare only specifically annotated properties with JaVers?

Tags: hibernate, orm, annotations, detach, javers

I have the following domain model. NB Jackson @JsonView annotations for the fields:

```
public interface JSONInvoiceBasicView {

    }

    public interface JSONInvoiceWithLinesView extends JSONInvoiceBasicView {

    }

    public interface JSONInvoiceWithLinesViewExt extends JSONInvoiceWithLinesView { 
    }

}

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="ERP_PU")
@Entity 
@Table(name="INVOICE")
public class Invoice extends FrameworkEntity {

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "PK_INVOICE_GEN", sequenceName = "PK_INVOICE_GEN", allocationSize=1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "PK_INVOICE_GEN")
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceBasicView.class)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="invoiceLine", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<InvoiceLine> lines = new ArrayList<InvoiceLine>();

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "DATE")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceBasicView.class)
    private Date startDate;

    //...
}

@PersistenceUnit(unitName="ERP_PU")
@Entity 
@Table(name="INVOICE_LINE")
public class InvoiceLine extends FrameworkEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_INVOICE")
    @JsonBackReference
    private Invoice invoice;

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)
    private BigDecimal amount;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name="FK_GOOD")
    @JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesExtView.class)
    private Good good;

    //...
}
@PersistenceUnit(unitName="ERP_PU")
@Entity 
@Table(name="GOOD")
public class Good extends FrameworkEntity {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DESCRIPTION", length=200)
    private String description;

//...
}
```

So - my problem is that I am retrieving only subgraph of the entire object graph, e.g. only Invoice and InvoiceLine entities with the fields annotated with `@JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)`, i.e. I am not going further and I am not retrieving invoice.invoiceLine[i].good entity. My question is - **can I prune the JaVers diff process, can I ask JaVers to compare only subset of the object graph - that subset that is annotated e.g. with `@JsonView(JSONInvoiceView.JSONInvoiceWithLinesView.class)`?**

My question mentions Jackson @JsonView annotations on the fields of entities but I guess - if JaVers support such filtering of observed properties, then this filtering can be done by any set of annotations approproate for fields/properites - be they Jackson or custom created.

I have heard about @DiffIgnore JaVers anotation, I am looking for the generalization and streamlining of this mechanism.

My scenario is - I am retrieving subgraph, I am sending ir to Angular fronent and then I am getting updated subgraph from Angular and I want to merge it back into my backend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a new annotation for that - `@DiffInclude`. It works as a positive filter for class' properties.

`@DiffInclude` — declares a property as visible by JaVers. Other properties in a given class are ignored (unless explicitly included). Including is opposite approach to Ignoring, like blacklisting vs whitelisting. You can use only one approach for a given class.

see https://javers.org/documentation/domain-configuration/#property-level-annotations

Comment: Most times you don't actually want everything logged, but only essential properties (definitely our case). Making sure that developers remember to exclude that specific property/getter whenever they add one, seems a bit like Windows automatically restarting the computer to install updates. Not the best.